# How do I programmatically filter last 52 weeks on the most recent date of my dataframe?

Tags: r

I am trying to programmatically filter my dataframe on the last 52 weeks from the most completed week in my dataframe. The most recent date is '04-21-2019'. This data will be loaded weekly, and I am trying to avoid filtering on the data manually.

I know there is lubridate. But I do not know which function would filter my data on the last 52 weeks based weeks. Would the better solution filter on 365 days instead?

The table looks like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Date (week) |     Product      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Apr 21, 19     |         A        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Apr 21, 19     |         B        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Apr 21, 19     |         C        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Apr 14, 19     |         A        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Apr 14, 19     |         B        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Apr 14, 19     |         C        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

and so on

The ideal result would give me a table with the last 52 weeks of data available.

Comment: One approach would be to pick an arbitrary starting date and calculate weeks elapsed since then for every date in your data. Then only keep data where  [weeks_elapsed to today] - [weeks_elapsed for row] <= 52.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you can use {lubridate}.
If I understand your question well, this should be what you are looking for:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

text_date <- '04-21-2019'
last_date <- mdy(text_date)
first_date <- last_date - weeks(52)

data <- tibble(
  date = c("04-21-2019", "01-21-2019", "08-21-2018", "04-21-2018"),
  product = LETTERS[1:4]
)

data %>% 
  mutate(date = mdy(date)) %>% 
  filter(date >= first_date, date <= last_date)
```

*Please, for your next question on SO, could you provide a reproducible example, with a usable dataframe.*